# How to set the one-to-one relationship with fluent api in this case? (EF6)

Tags: entity-framework-6, one-to-one, ef-fluent-api

I have this two entities:

```
    public partial class Ficheros
        {
            public Guid Idfichero { get; set; }
            public long Iddocumento { get; set; }
            public byte[] Fichero { get; set; }

            public virtual Documentos IddocumentoNavigation { get; set; }
        }

public partial class Documentos
    {
        public Documentos()
        {
            ElementosDocumentos = new HashSet<ElementosDocumentos>();
        }

        public long Iddocumento { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public long? IdtipoDocumento { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public decimal? Espacio { get; set; }
        public string Unidades { get; set; }
        public long? Bytes { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ElementosDocumentos> ElementosDocumentos { get; set; }
        public virtual Ficheros Ficheros { get; set; }
        public virtual DocumentosTipos IdtipoDocumentoNavigation { get; set; }
    }
```

In the database, IDFichero is an uniqueidentifier and in Documentos the IDDocumento is a big int autoincrement. The main table is Documentos, that has one and only one fichero, and it is requiered.

The examples that I have seen, it would make me that IDFichero was IDDocumento, but to store a file in the database I need that the ID is a uniqueidentifier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship you are describing in EF terms is one-to-one FK association with both ends required, `Documentos` being the *principal* and `Ficheros` the *dependent*.

EF does not support explicit FK for this type of association, so start by removing the `Ficheros.Iddocumento` property:

```
public partial class Ficheros
{
    public Guid Idfichero { get; set; }
    public byte[] Fichero { get; set; }

    public virtual Documentos IddocumentoNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

then use the following fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Documentos>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Ficheros)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(e => e.IddocumentoNavigation)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("Iddocumento"));
```