# Entity Framework 6 defining 1 to 1 relationship with Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to define a 1:1 relationship between two entities. I realize this is not possible in SQL, however from my understanding EF should be able to enforce this constraint on entities in memory before they are allowed to be persisted to the database. I have the following code in my Context class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Dependent>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Principal)
                .WithRequiredDependent()
```

However, EF will happily allow me to do the following without throwing an exception:

```
context.Dependents.Add(new Dependent()
{
   Principle = null
});
context.SaveChanges();
```

The method definition of `HasRequired` reads:

> Configures a required relationship from this entity type. Instances of
>   the entity type will not be able to be saved to the database unless
>   this relationship is specified. The foreign key in the database will
>   be non-nullable.

Is there something I am missing here?

EDIT: here is the concrete example in which the unexpected behavior occurs:

Model Classes:

```
public class TeamMatchDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int TeamMatchDetailId { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3), Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TeamMatchDetail>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Team)
                .WithRequiredDependent()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Repository:

```
context.TeamMatchDetails.Add(new TeamMatchDetail()
{
    Team = null
});
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to happen in latest EF6.1.3 - I'm getting `DbUpdateException` from `SaveChanges` call.

Comment: @IvanStoev I've just checked I'm also using EF 6.1.3. I've added the code in my question.

Comment: `public int TeamId { get; set; }` shouldn't be there. See [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations), [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367293/how-to-set-the-one-to-one-relationship-with-fluent-api-in-this-case-ef6/43368219#43368219).

Comment: Thank you so much @Ivan Stoev, this ended up solving my issue