# One to Zero Relationship not working?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, one-to-one

I have been trying to establish an optional One-to-One relationship between 2 entities unsuccessfully.  I can do it by creating a Unique Constraint on the **RTUDEVICE** tables `DeviceId`, but I am trying to do it the "right way" through the Fluent API

What am I doing wrong?

**Relationship Explanation**:
One **DEVICE** record may have one-and-only-one record in the **RTUDEVICE** table.

**ENTITIES:**
Below are simplified versions of the actual classes...

```
public partial class Device
{
    public Int Id { get; set; }

    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    public virtual RTUDevice RTUDevice { get; set; }
}

public partial class RTUDevice
{
    public Int Id { get; set; }

    public int DeviceId { get; set; }

    public bool IsCRMAlarmDevice { get; set; }

    public bool HasCustomRegisters { get; set; }

    public bool HasGasQualityRegisters { get; set; }

    public bool HistoryVerified { get; set; }

    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

**MAPPING:**
I did many attempts using various online example without success...the failing code is commented-out.

```
public DeviceMap(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ToTable("Device", "dbo")
        .HasKey(m => m.Id);

    Property(m => m.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
        .IsRequired();

    Property(m => m.DeviceName)
        .IsUnicode(false)
        .HasMaxLength(100)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("UX_Device_AlternateKey") { IsUnique = true }));

        //modelBuilder.Entity<RTUDevice>()
        //    .HasOptional(e => e.Device)
        //    .WithRequired(e => e.RTUDevice)
        //    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}

public RTUDeviceMap(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ToTable("RTUDevice", "dbo")
        .HasKey(m => m.Id);

    Property(m => m.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
        .IsRequired();

    Property(e => e.DeviceId)
        .IsRequired();

    Property(e => e.IsCRMAlarmDevice )
        .IsRequired();

    Property(e => e.HasCustomRegisters)
        .IsRequired();

    Property(e => e.HasGasQualityRegisters)
        .IsRequired();

    Property(e => e.HistoryVerified)
        .IsRequired();

        // One-to-Zero-or-One relationship
        //modelBuilder.Entity<RTUDevice>()
        //    .HasOptional(e => e.Device)
        //    .WithRequired(e => e.RTUDevice)
        //    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        // One-to-Zero-or-One relationship
        //modelBuilder.Entity<RTUDevice>()
        //    .HasRequired(e => e.Device)
        //    .WithMany()
        //    .HasForeignKey(c => c.DeviceId)
        //    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Comment: Remove the `DeviceId` property from `RTUDevice` and use `MapKey` fluent API - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367293/how-to-set-the-one-to-one-relationship-with-fluent-api-in-this-case-ef6/43368219#43368219)

Answer (score 0):

You should just use Id as the PK (as well as FK) in RTUDevice entity and get rid of DeviceId. Then define the relationship as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
            .HasKey(it => it.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<RTUDevice>()
            .HasKey(it => it.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
            .HasOptional(it => it.RTUDevice)
            .WithRequired(it => it.Device);
```

If DeviceId needs to be used explicitly for mapping, use the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
            .HasOptional(it => it.RTUDevice)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(it => it.Device)
            .Map(it => it.MapKey("DeviceId"));
```

Comment: This generates the following error: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'RTUDevice' and 'Device'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations

Comment: please try using .WithOptionalPrincipal(it => it.Device) as updated in the answer

Comment: .WithOptionalPrincipal(it => it.Device) generates the same error