# Entity Framework Code First and linked entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have AspNetUser entity :

```
public partial class AspNetUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    [Index(IsClustered = false, IsUnique = true)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    ....
```

Interfaces:

```
public interface IProfile
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string Nickname { get; set; }
}

public interface IMembershipEntity
{
    string AspNetUserId { get; set; }
    AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
}
```

And 2 entities, each of them has link to AspNetUser as FK (both implement IProfile and IMembershipEntity):

```
public partial class Driver : IMembershipEntity, IProfile
{

    #region IProfile
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region IMembershipEntity
    public string AspNetUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AspNetUserId")]
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    #endregion

   ... driver fields


public class User : BaseEntity, IMembershipEntity, IProfile
{
    #region IMembershipEntity
    public string AspNetUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region IProfile
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    #endregion

    .... user fields
}
```

right now I need a method which need get FirstName/LastName from AspNetUser, like this:

```
        var element = (from i in db.AspNetUsers
                    select new UserElementDomain()
                    {
                        UserId = i.Id,
                        CompanyName = i.Company.Name,
                        FirstName = (get FirstName here),
                        LastName = (get LastName here),
                        RoleName = i.AspNetRoles.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                        SMSnumber = i.SMSnumber,
                        UserName = i.UserName,
                        .....
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

How to do it?
I can add 2 properties to AspNetUser, like:

```
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
```

but how to say, that it should be one or zero link, without creating UserId/DriverId

And even with it, then I have to write code like:

```
FirstName = (i.User!=null)? i.User.FirstName : ((i.Driver!=null)?i.Driver.FirstName : String.Empty)
```

and I don't like this code, because when I add one more Entity I have to review all code and add one more condition. How to do it correctly? Probably, using interfaces/inheritance?

Comment: Is `AspNetUserId` also a PK in the `User` and `Driver` tables? In other words, do they implement [Shared Primary Key Association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations)?

Comment: @IvanStoev no and can't be (restriction from customer, he wants to have separate ids)

Comment: You are in trouble then because EF6 has quite limited support of one-to-one FK relationships. Any chance this to be EF Core?

Comment: @IvanStoev no chance right now...

Comment: Too bad. You have to sacrifice the explicit FK properties `AspNetUserId` from both interface and entities, and rely on navigation properties only. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011305/entity-framework-one-to-one-referentialconstraint-is-mapped-to-a-store-gener/50054609#50054609 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367293/how-to-set-the-one-to-one-relationship-with-fluent-api-in-this-case-ef6/43368219#43368219 etc.

Comment: the data structure is strange, and you said you will add more entity like this. all sub-entities have a copied properties set, and the real FirstName will depend on which entity is on first check. by your current code, if User.FirstName="A" & Driver.FirstName="B", then result is "A" only. if you have a new entity called "Employee", who know which name will be the real firstname if you dont hard code it like this? why don't you add the profile properties to "AspNetUser"? then no data could be duplicated.

Comment: @Dongdong why strange? There are 2 types of users (User and Driver) with different structure of profiles

Comment: @IvanStoev could you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710270/entity-framework-6-x-and-one-to-one-relationship ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I saw duplicated code before, but rarely saw duplicated data structure.

by your current code, if User.FirstName="A" & Driver.FirstName="B", then result is "A" only. if you have a new entity called "Employee", who knows which name will be the real firstname in 3 of entities, if you don't hard code it with your current style?

your current code could simplify to :

```
i.User?.FirstName ?? i.Driver?.FirstName ?? i.Whatever?.FirstName ?? String.Empty
```

but is it the real data you want to manage?

I give you 2 other options:

1. add properties to root entity, it's AspNetUser in your case:

   ```
   public class AspNetUser
   {
   ....
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string Nickname { get; set; }
   ....
   }
   ```
2. Manage common profiles in 1 entity

   ```
   public class AspNetUser
   {
   ....
   public virtual AspNetUserProfile AspNetUserProfile { get; set; }
   }
   public class AspNetUserProfile
   {
   [Key]
   public string Id { get; set; }

   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string Nickname { get; set; }
   ....
   [ForeignKey("Id")]
   public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
   }
   ```

then in your code:

```
   db.AspNetUsers.Select(i => new UserElementDomain()
                {
                    UserId = i.Id,
                    CompanyName = i.Company.Name,
                    FirstName = i.AspNetUserProfile?.FirstName,
                    LastName = i.AspNetUserProfile?.LastName,
                    RoleName = i.AspNetRoles.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                    SMSnumber = i.SMSnumber,
                    UserName = i.UserName,
                    .....
                })
```

if Driver/User/Empolyee want to get FirstName, just use:

```
Empolyee.AspNetUser.AspNetUserProfile?.FirstName
```

Comment: approach #1 is like it done today, but it does not like for my architect. Also, it's only common part of properties, Driver and User has individual properties too

Comment: also, about `i.User?.FirstName ?? i.Driver?.FirstName ?? i.Whatever?.FirstName ?? String.Empty` is compilation error: "An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator"