# Entity Framework 6.X and one-to-one relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I have the following model:

```
public partial class Driver 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    ......
}


public partial class AspNetUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
    ......
}
```

and the following mapping:

```
        this.HasOptional(c => c.Driver)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(a => a.AspNetUser)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("AspNetUserId"));
```

It creates correct DB model, adds nullable AspNetUserId FK to Driver table.

But how to link one object with another in code. I don't have AspNetUserId property, so, I try to set object, like this:

```
        _db.Drivers.Attach(driver);
        _db.AspNetUsers.Attach(aspNetUser);
        driver.AspNetUser = aspNetUser;

        _db.SaveChanges();
```

but then I got an exception :

> "An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign
>   key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property
>   will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the
>   source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be
>   made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types.
>   See the InnerException for details."
>
> "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."

How to solve it with EF 6.X ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening when the `Driver` is already associated with `AspNetUser`. When you attach the `driver` with `AspNetUser` property being `null`, EF assumes the original value of `AspNetUserId` being `null` and generates update statement with `AspNetUserId IS NULL` additional criteria, which of course does not match the existing record, the command returns 0 records affected and EF generates the exception in question.

The solution is (1) to load the original `Driver.AspNetUser` property value from the database before setting the new value. Also, in order to correctly handle the case when the new `AspNetUser` is already associated with a different `Driver`, you should (2) load `AspNetUser.Driver` property as well:

```
_db.Drivers.Attach(driver);
_db.AspNetUsers.Attach(aspNetUser);

_db.Entry(driver).Reference(e => e.AspNetUser).Load(); // (1)
_db.Entry(aspNetUser).Reference(e => e.Driver).Load(); // (2)

driver.AspNetUser = aspNetUser;

_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hmm, I've tested it - was able to duplicate your original exception, and this really fixed it for me. EF6.2 if that matters,

Comment: If that helps in my tests `driver` and `aspNetUser` are disconnected entities. And `driver.AspNetUser == null && aspNetUser.Driver == null` before calling `Attach`.

Comment: found a problem, my `driver` was not added to db context at all